# C++ Previous text erased and replaced by new text in terminal

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){

char choice;

do{
    double x;
    double y;
    char z;
    double sum;

    cout << "Pick a operation + - * /" << endl;
    cin >> z;
    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter another number" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    if (z == '+'){
        sum = x + y;
        cout << "Answer: " << sum << endl;
    }
    else if (z == '-'){
        sum = x - y;
        cout << "Answer: " << sum << endl;
    }
    else if (z == '-'){
        sum = x - y;
        cout << "Answer: " << sum << endl;
    }
    else if (z == '*'){
        sum = x * y;
        cout << "Answer: " << sum << endl;
    }
    else if (z == '/'){
        sum = x / y;
        cout << "Answer: " << sum << endl;
    }
    cout << "Would you like to enter another equation? (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
} while (choice != 'n');
if (choice == 'n'){
    return 0;
}


system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do  is make it so that instead of each new `cout` going to another line, the replaces the current line. Basically, everything will happen in one line except for the     `cin`     which will appear in the line below the `cout`. I know i could use `\r` but then the `cin` will try to overwrite the `cout`. I want the `cin` input to be erased and then the `cout` will replace the previous `cout`.

I'm a total beginner so I don't really know what to do.

Comment: There is no standard way to do that.

Comment: Really? There is no possible way to do that?

Comment: I didn't say that.  I said there is no *standard* way to do it.  Whatever you come up with is not going to be portable.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank You.

Comment: Yeah. Everybody does their consoles differently. [Probably the closest to portability you'll get is with a curses library.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library))

Comment: You're on Windows and you've been made aware of the portability issues. Probably one of the easiest ways is to just clear the screen and hope for no flicker.  `system("cls");`

Comment: Ya, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern console emulators are fast enough that you can clear the screen and simply re-print the text you want to keep, without noticeable flickering.  As mentioned, you can also use a curses library.

You knew about this, but: many terminals will do this when you print the **carriage return** character, `\r`.  Historically, when teletypes had physical typewriter print wheels and carriages, this would return the carriage to the left position and allow overwriting.  On some machines (including classic Macintoshes), this will do something else, but it will work on most consoles today, including Windows `cmd.exe`, OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

While there are ways to do that, none of them are standard. This link shows the ANSI escape sequences, but every terminal is different and remember documentation is your friend.[ANSI Escapes](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c327.html)